# Listings and Updating Associated IDs - Rails 4, Form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-attributes

I have a model called `Foo`, which has many `bars`. I want to be able to add / remove  `foo.bars` by adding or removing associated `foo.bars.ids`. How can I achieve this?

I tried:

#### Foo#edit

```
def edit
  @bars = @foo.bars
end
```

#### Form

```
<%= form_for @foo, url: edit_foo_path(@foo.id) do |p| %>
  ...
  <%= p.text_area @bars %> #<= returns undefined method `Collection..' for `foo`
  ...
  <%= p.fields_for @foo.bars do |b| %>
    <%= b.text_area :ids %> #<= returns in 'unpermitted param 'bar' on #update' 
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I'm thinking `fields_for` would not work here anyway since I am not updating  `bar`'s attributes. Instead, I want to be able to add / remove `foo.bars` by listings their `ids`

Comment: Do you want to destroy the `Bar` instances associated with the `Foo` instance or just "unlink" them? (i.e. remove the `foo_id` value from the `bar` record)

Comment: @MrYoshiji just unlink, but Foo has many `bars` via the `has_many_through  association` so there is no `foo_id` attribute in `Bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook into the `Foo#bar_ids` and `Foo#bar_ids=` methods which the has_many association gives you.  You could do this via checkboxes for example.

```
<% form_for @foo do |f| %>
  <% @bars.each do |bar| %>
    <div class="bar--checkbox">
      <%= check_box_tag "foo[bar_ids]", bar.id, @foo.bar_ids.include?(bar.id) %>
      <%= bar.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Now, in params you'll get something like

```
params = {:id => 123, :foo => {:bar_ids => [1, 5, 8, 10]})
```

and you can do the usual update controller code:

```
@foo = Foo.where(:id => params[:id])
@updated = @foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
```

which is like doing this:

```
@foo.bar_ids = [1, 5, 8, 10]
@foo.save
```

**NOTE** - in your code you're setting @bars to be @foo's current bars.  It could be all the bars in the system for example, which would be better in terms of adding and removing whichever bars you want.

Comment: nice! ended up using `text_area_tag` instead of a form helper and added a `param` parser in my controller action. Thanks for your help!